# Xsane imaging launches after 2-3 minutes for all scanners in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: scanner, sane, xsane

I am very new to Linux. Whenever i open xsane imaging it takes more than 2 minutes to open. I tried different applications such as xsane image scanning, simplescan, gsca2pdf etc but no chnage. I also tried these applications on different scanners but still same issue crops up.

I used Kodak i1190 and Canon-DRC-225 scanners? Is it scanners issue or something wron with Ubuntu or SANE? Please help if these is any workaround to this